# How can I disable these boxes in intellij for the AtomOne Theme

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]
I am using the Atom One Theme and these boxes appear to indicate errors. Is there any way I can change them to underline like the other themes?

Comment: This theme looks similar https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18364-neo-theme

Answer (score 0):

Here is the bug in Atom One repository:
https://github.com/subtheme-dev/atom-one/issues/9

Downgrading could help

Answer (score 0):

Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > General > Errors and Warnings > Change bordered to whichever you prefer